# Pointwise convergence and the convergence of a distribution sequence.

Tags: convergence-divergence, distribution-theory, uniform-convergence, weak-convergence

The sequence of functions $f_n(x)=\{tanh(nx)\}_{n=0}^{\infty}$ does not converge uniformly to $f(x)=sgn(x)$ but only pointwise.

Is it then, still possible that the sequence of distributions

\begin{equation}
\langle T_{f_n},\phi(x)\rangle=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f_n(x)\phi(x)dx
\end{equation}
 to converge to the correspoding distribution

\begin{equation}
\langle T_f,\phi(x)\rangle=-\int_{-\infty}^{0}\phi(x)dx+\int_{0}^{\infty}\phi(x)dx
\end{equation}

of $f(x)=sgn(x)$?

The question rises from a Theorem which suggests that since we do know that $\{f_n\}_{n=0}^{\infty}$ consists of continuous functions which converge uniformly to a funtion $f$, then the correspoding sequence of distributions converges to the distribution $T_f$.

Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\begin{align}
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}(f_n(x)-f(x))\phi(x)dx&=\int_{0}^{\infty} ((f_n(x)-f(x))\phi(x)+(f_n(-x)-f(-x))\phi(-x))dx\\\\
&=\int_{0}^{\infty} (f_n(x)-f(x))(\phi(x)-\phi(-x))dx
\end{align}$$

where we used the fact that $f_n$ and $f$ are odd to arrive at the last equality.

Now, $f_n(x)-f(x)=-\frac{e^{-nx}}{\cosh(nx)}$.  Let's look at the following

$$\begin{align}
\left|\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}(f_n(x)-f(x))\phi(x)dx\right|&=\left|\int_{0}^{\infty}(f_n(x)-f(x))\left(\phi(x)-\phi(-x)\right)dx\right|\\\\
&\le \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{e^{-nx}}{\cosh(nx)} \left|\phi(x)-\phi(-x)\right|\,dx\\\\
&\le 2M \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-nx}\,dx\\\\
&=2M/n
\end{align}$$

where $M$ is a finite, upper bound of $\phi$.  Recall that $\phi$ is $L^1$ and continuous on $(-\infty,\infty)$, and therefore is bounded.

Now, given $\epsilon>0$, choose an $N\ge 2M/\epsilon$ so that $\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{e^{-nx}}{\cosh(nx)} \left|\phi(x)-\phi(-x)\right|\,dx<\epsilon$ whenever n>N.  This completes the proof.

Comment: Thank you so much for your detailed proof! I am going throught it atm and I would like to ask: Is it $f_n(x)-f(x)=-\frac{e^{-nx}}{cosh(nx)}$ or should it be without the minus sign?

Comment: Also, I would like to ask why the inequality: 1.78€M\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{e^{-nx}}{cosh(nx)}dx\leq 2M\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-nx}dx$ holds. I am not able to see it :/

Comment: You are welcome.  My pleasure.  The minus sign is correct.  Upon applying the absolute value, the minus sign is absorbed.

Comment: Oh yes, I can see that it is absorbed, but when I calculate it, I just find it to be with a minus sign. I will check it again :)

Comment: The first inequality comes from applying $|\int g dx|\le\int |g| dx$.  The second inequality comes from applying ($1$) $|\phi_{+}-\phi_{-}|< 2M$  and (2) $1/\cosh(nx)<1$.

Comment: $f_n-f = -\frac{e^{-nx}}{\cosh nx}$ is correct.  There is indeed a minus sign.

Comment: I meant without* minus. But nevertheless, I will double check :) Ok, now I see that $1/cosh(nx)<1$. Everything is clear! Thank you my friend!

Comment: You're quite welcome!  Glad I was able to help.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it does.  Note that for any $\delta > 0$, convergence is uniform outside $(-\delta, \delta)$.

For any test function $\phi$ and $\epsilon > 0$, take 
$\delta$ so $\int_{-\delta}^\delta |\phi(x)|\; dx < \epsilon$.  Then
if $n$ is large enough that $|f_n - f| < \epsilon$ outside $(-\delta,\delta)$,
$$\left|\langle T_{f_n}, \phi \rangle - \langle T_f, \phi \rangle \right| 
\le \epsilon \int_{\mathbb R} |\phi(x)| \; dx + \int_{-\delta}^\delta |\phi(x)|\; dx \le (1 + \|\phi\|_{L^1}) \epsilon$$

Comment: Can you be a little more detailed? I am new to the whole concept of distributions and I am not yet able to understand the part with the inequalities.